# Twitter Bootstrap: the affix part can't scroll

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, scroll

I have a affix part on page, it keep some distance from the window's top,

What I want is, when the page scroll, it will scroll too, but when it touch the window's top, it will fixed in that position

I have use `data-spy="affix"`, but it does't succss, here is the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hh54188/v9xqw/3/)

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this out: http://jsfiddle.net/panchroma/v9xqw/4/

I edited this line

```
<div class="demo" data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="260"></div> <!-- data-offset-top is the distance you need to scroll before the demo div is affixed -->
```

and added this to your CSS

```
.demo.affix  
{           /* specify what you want to happen when the demo div is affixed */
top:0;
}
```

Hope that does the trick for you!